# Applescript variable as folder

Tags: applescript

I am trying to write an AppleScript that takes in a selection of files (important to note, they are not all in the same folder) that renames each file to the name of the folder it is in. So far I have what is below, but I get an error which reads "Can't get container of 1." number -1728 from <> of 1.

```
tell application "Finder"

set all_files to every item of (choose file with prompt "Choose the Files you'd like to rename:" with multiple selections allowed) as list

    repeat with a from 1 to length of all_files
        set folder_name to container of a
        set file_name to folder_name
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because you try to get the `container` of the index variable `a`

Basically a line is missing to get the reference to a file and you want to set the **name** of the file to the **name** of the folder.

```
tell application "Finder"

    set all_files to every item of (choose file with prompt "Choose the Files you'd like to rename:" with multiple selections allowed) as list

    repeat with a from 1 to length of all_files
        set a_file to item a of all_files
        set folder_name to name of container of a_file
        set name of a_file to folder_name
    end repeat
end tell
```

Note: Be aware that the code removes all extensions of the files.